# I need a JQuery IP Mask plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, ip-address

Is there a good IP Mask plugin for JQuery? I've tried [Masked Input Plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) but it doesn't IP Addresses with less than 12 digits. Then I've tried [meioMask](http://www.meiocodigo.com/projects/meiomask/) and this doesn't work with less than 12 digits either. Any suggestions?

Comment: what do u mean "doesn't work with less than 12 digits"?? could you show me some examples???

Comment: IPv6 is more I guess is this issue so it doesn't work with IPv4? Also please post some examples / code anything to help with what you are doing you can not get a reasonable answer with out a reasonable question. So all I can say is 42.

Comment: Do you absolutely need to be a masked input or if the input was validated on a button clicked it could be fine too?

Comment: @Ozaki: it's a jquery plugin, what good is my code gonna do?!

@Philippe: I already have a validator, i was hoping for a nice masked input as well.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa You need to be more specific it is NOT an issue that it can't do less than 12 digits its that it CAN'T do 1-3 digits per field.

Comment: @Ozaki, you're right! I should've been clear.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can find your answer in this post :

http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/

and a demo for you to try

http://mlntn.com/demos/jquery-ipaddress/

Comment: No documentation. It's a pain to try and get working. Retrieving values for instance.

Comment: Dead link... no 404 but blank page.

Comment: Try this in the meantime : http://web.archive.org/web/20140219174935/http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/

Answer (score 3):

This is an older post however for someone who wants an easy way to manipulate multiple inputs, without using a bulking plugin, or having to worry about documentation or methods, here's a simple class selector method that does it all for you.  Its IPv4 only but it sounds like your needs are pretty simple.

```
//jQuery 1.9+ selector pattern,
//To get working with an older version
//Swap first line to $(".ip").bind('keydown',function(e){
//To get working with jQuery versions support .live
//$(".ip").live('keydown',function(e){
$(document).on('keydown',".ip",function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var sections = $(this).val().split('.');
    //Only check last section!
    var isInt       = ((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code >= 96 && code <= 105));
    var hasSlash    = $(this).val().indexOf("/") == -1;
    if(isInt){
        if(hasSlash){
            if(sections.length < 4){
                //We can add another octet
                var val = parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]+String.fromCharCode(code));
                if(val > 255 || parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]) == 0){
                    $(this).val($(this).val()+"."+String.fromCharCode(code));
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            } else {
                //Lets prevent string manipulations, our string is long enough
                var val = parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]+String.fromCharCode(code));
                if(val > 255 || parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]) == 0){
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            var cidr_split = $(this).val().split('/');
            var target_val = parseInt(cidr_split[1]+String.fromCharCode(code));
            return (target_val < 33 && target_val.toString().length < 3 && parseInt(cidr_split[1]) != 0);
        }
    } else if(code == 191){
        //CIDR Slash
        return ($(this).val().indexOf("/") == -1);
    } else if(code == 8 || code == 46 || code == 9 || code == 13){
        return true;
    }
    return false
});
```

To break this down for understanding, you bind the class "ip" in your input, it will handle the rest automatically :D This version supports CIDR notation (eg: 192.168.1.1/16) it only allows valid addresses to be input, to remove CIDR function you can use use the following snippet (not tested)

```
//jQuery 1.9+ selector pattern,
//To get working with an older version
//Swap first line to $(".ip").bind('keydown',function(e){
//To get working with jQuery versions support .live
//$(".ip").live('keydown',function(e){
$(document).on('keydown',".ip",function(e){
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    var sections = $(this).val().split('.');
    //Only check last section!
    var isInt       = ((code >= 48 && code <= 57) || (code >= 96 && code <= 105));
    if(isInt){
        if(sections.length < 4){
            //We can add another octet
            var val = parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]+String.fromCharCode(code));
            if(val > 255 || parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]) == 0){
                $(this).val($(this).val()+"."+String.fromCharCode(code));
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            //Lets prevent string manipulations, our string is long enough
            var val = parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]+String.fromCharCode(code));
            if(val > 255 || parseInt(sections[sections.length-1]) == 0){
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    } else if(code == 8 || code == 46 || code == 9 || code == 13){
        return true;
    }
    return false
});
```

I am providing the code here for two purposes 1) This is something i believe needs to be addressed, 2) i hope to contribute to the world

The snippet is not designed to be pulled apart, nor support IPv6, if you need IPv6 Support please see https://code.google.com/p/jquery-input-ip-address-control/ that anyulled suggested.

But aside from the complex syntax, it breaks the octets apart, and only checks the "active" octet, it supports any VALID address (0.0.0.0, 0.0.0.0/0, ect) so use wisely it does not do any fancy checking other than preventing invalid input.  If you're looking for a checker, please see Santiago Elvira Ramirez's post about the IP Address validator.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using this plugin https://code.google.com/p/jquery-input-ip-address-control/

Answer (score 1):

The working examples from the Masked Input Plugin - 
http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

Are less than 12 characters:

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("#date").mask("99/99/9999");
   $("#phone").mask("(999) 999-9999");
   $("#tin").mask("99-9999999");
   $("#ssn").mask("999-99-9999");
});
```

They have working examples which are running perfectly?

What is exatly is your issue and can you post anymore in depth information?

```
jQuery(function($){
    $("#MyElementID").mask("10.0.0.0"); //Does this not work?
});
```

Are you trying to counter for 1-3 digits in each field?

eg to be able to.

```
$("#MyElementID").mask("1.0.0.0"); //this
$("#MyElementID").mask("10.10.10.10"); //or this
$("#MyElementID").mask("100.100.100.100"); //or this
```

If you be more descriptive you can get help..

If you are after that you can try something simpler by watermarking the input box rather than enforcing a mask, so you can vary the numbers that can be entered.
See Jquery-Watermark  - http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/

Comment: Yes, i need 1-3 digits in each field, no specific number of digits. And I'm not sure how the watermark plugin would help.

Comment: Someone please explain reason for downvoting this?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but i need to know how to allow for masking 1-3 digits.

Answer (score 1):

i found this and you don´t need to install plugins

```
function fnValidateIPAddress(ipaddr) {
    //Remember, this function will validate only Class C IP.
    //change to other IP Classes as you need
    ipaddr = ipaddr.replace( /\s/g, "") //remove spaces for checking
    var re = /^\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}$/; //regex. check for digits and in
                                          //all 4 quadrants of the IP
    if (re.test(ipaddr)) {
        //split into units with dots "."
        var parts = ipaddr.split(".");
        //if the first unit/quadrant of the IP is zero
        if (parseInt(parseFloat(parts[0])) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        //if the fourth unit/quadrant of the IP is zero
        if (parseInt(parseFloat(parts[3])) == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        //if any part is greater than 255
        for (var i=0; i<parts.length; i++) {
            if (parseInt(parseFloat(parts[i])) > 255){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```