# Input box for changing IP Address

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create an input field for an IP address, broadcast, and subnet. The inputs are used to change the ip of the server. Its an internal website.

I want to make it so that the user gets an input box that has the periods hardcoded into the text box. This way when they start typing, they only have to input the numbers and be able to tab to the next part of the ip. Or if the user enters 3 characters, it automatically sends him to the next part of the ip.

I don't know if this is something that can only be done with html and css or if this is more of a javascript application.

http://jsfiddle.net/3F2gM/1/

Thanks.

Comment: is this something you want us to write for you or is it something you  have tried and haven't figured out how to do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of existing question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183522/i-need-a-jquery-ip-mask-plugin

Comment: I looked on stack overflow, I wouldn't have thought of searching for a mask plugin. I'll read through that question. @Phil I was just looking for some general guidance on which route would be the best to go with.

Comment: Does it have to be in one input box? Or can you do a set of input boxes which takes the inputs and automatically changes focus and then concatenates the values?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [mask plugin](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/) - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/3F2gM/3/)

```
jQuery(function($){
   $("input").mask("9?99.9?99.9?99.9?99", {placeholder:" "});
});
```

Comment: @MiqdadAli see [Champs answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304612/input-box-for-changing-ip-address#12304985). It works.

Answer (score 5):

[jQuery IP plugin](http://mlntn.com/2009/12/30/jquery-ip-address-plugin/) can be also be useful in your case

[Working DEMO](http://mlntn.com/demos/jquery-ipaddress/)