# JQuery or Javascript Input IP address mask

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have used jquery masked input plugin as per stackoverflow question

[Input box for changing IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12304612/input-box-for-changing-ip-address/12304730#comment19988112_12304730)

but It didn't worked for me .

I have used it like `$("input").mask("9?99.9?99.9?99.9?99", {placeholder:" "});`

This demo (http://jsfiddle.net/3F2gM/3/ ) i found in previous question , but it didnt works

Comment: That one looks working for me, what exactly do you mean not working here?

Comment: That mask plugin does not work for IP address at all. It does not restrict input between 1-255. See the second answer in the linked question.

Comment: on this example http://jsfiddle.net/3F2gM/3/  please input 123.123.123.123 as IP and just leave the textbox

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me this way:

First, I added jquery-mask in the html:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"></script>
```

Then I typed the text field with the class .ip_address:

```
<label>ip:</label> <input class="ip_address" type="text" name="ip">
```

by last:

```
$('.ip_address').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', { translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true } } });
```

Answer (score 4):

This may help you:-
I have 4 input fields, each of its border was hided. Only the parent of the input field has the border, which will make it to look like a single text box.
After that, allow the user to enter only 3 characters by using **maxLength**, once the user reached the maximum length, focus on to next field.
The code follows:- [Link](https://jsfiddle.net/5uLo9tjg/)

**HTML**

```
<div>    
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="onlythree" />.    
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="onlythree" />.    
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="onlythree" />.    
<input type="text" maxlength="3" class="onlythree" />    
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.onlythree{    
width: 50px;    
border: 0;    
}    
div{    
border: 1px solid gray;    
display: inline-block;    
}
```

**JS**

```
$(".onlythree").keyup(function () {    
if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {    
$(this).next('.onlythree').focus();    
}    
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually I needed something similar to what you needed and what I did was to contact Igor Escobar, the author of [Jquery Mask Plugin](http://igorescobar.github.io/jQuery-Mask-Plugin/). There is not a complete built in way to do it yet, so he directed me to one option this could be accomplished and here I share the result:.

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="networkSectionIpAddress" class="ip_address" >
```

**Javascript:**

```
var options =  { 
            onKeyPress: function(cep, event, currentField, options){
//            console.log('An key was pressed!:', cep, ' event: ', event,'currentField: ', currentField, ' options: ', options);
                if(cep){
                  var ipArray = cep.split(".");
                  var lastValue = ipArray[ipArray.length-1];
                  if(lastValue != "" && parseInt(lastValue) > 255){
                      ipArray[ipArray.length-1] =  '255';
                      var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
                      currentField.attr('value',resultingValue);
                  }
            }             
        }};

        $('.ip_address').mask("000.000.000.000", options);
```

I hope this information is helpful for those using this great JQuery Mask plugin :)

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem differently. In the above example, the only change is the last octet, I change everything, because for quick commissioning can enter numbers greater than 255. In addition, when viewed through firebug, the value is set in the input, and the displayed text is the same as the user enters.

HTML

```
<input type="text" name="vpn_ip" class="mask-ipv4" value="">
```

Java Script

```
var options =  { 
    onChange: function(cep, event, currentField, options){
        if(cep){
            var ipArray = cep.split(".");
            for (i in ipArray){
                if(ipArray[i] != "" && parseInt(ipArray[i]) > 255){
                    ipArray[i] =  '255';
                }
            }
            var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
            $(currentField).val(resultingValue);
        }
    }
};

$('.mask-ipv4').mask("000.000.000.000", options);
```

Comment: Languages other than English are not appropriate here, consider translating your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Valdivia's answer doesn't make sure that each item in the ip array <= 255, and will824's answer doesn't allow for < 3 digits for an item.

Here is a complete example based on their answers that meets both criteria.

```
var options =  { 
    onKeyPress: function(text, event, currentField, options){
                    if (text){
                        var ipArray = text.split(".");
                        var lastValue = ipArray[ipArray.length-1];
                        if(lastValue != "" && parseInt(lastValue) > 255){
                            ipArray[ipArray.length-1] = '255';
                            var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
                            currentField.text(resultingValue).val(resultingValue);
                        }
                    }             
                },
    translation: {
            'Z': {
                pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true
            }
    }
};

$(".ipaddr").mask("0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ", options);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getChar(event) {
    if (event.which == null) {
        if (event.keyCode < 32) return null;
        return String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode)
    }

    if (event.which != 0 && event.charCode != 0) {
        if (event.which < 32) return null; 
        return String.fromCharCode(event.which); 
    }
    return null; 
}



function maskIP(e){
    let key = getChar(e);
    
    
    if((!((key >= 0 && key <= 9) || key == '.'))  || this.value.length >= 15) e.preventDefault();
    if (this.value.indexOf('.') == -1){
        if (this.value.length >= 3 && key != '.') {
            e.preventDefault();    
        }
    }
    else{
        if(this.value.lastIndexOf('.') == this.value.length - 1 && key == '.') {
            e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        if ((this.value.length - this.value.lastIndexOf('.') > 3 && key != '.') || (key == '.' && this.value.split(".").length - 1 >= 3)) {
            e.preventDefault();    
        }
    }
}


serch = document.getElementById("#id of your element"); //can use others
serch.addEventListener('keypress', maskIP);
```

Comment: Please make sure, you do add some explanation along with the code sample. It enhances the essence of your explanation. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it works in my case.

```
var ip_options = { 
    translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /[0-9]/, optional: true } },
    onKeyPress: function(cep, event, currentField, options) {
        if(cep) {
            var ipArray = cep.split(".");
            for (i in ipArray){
                if(ipArray[i] != "" && parseInt(ipArray[i]) > 255){
                    ipArray[i] =  '255';
                }
            }
            var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
            $(currentField).val(resultingValue);
        }
    }
};

$('.ip_address').mask("0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ", ip_options);
```