# Don't let user to input wrong data - Improving IP address validation JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, maskedinput

I am trying to make a masked input field to input IP addresses. Almost every solution I found have flaws.

Here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55837333 is the best solution I found, but it is still lets me to enter values higher than 255. Basically it works, but when I am trying to change the entered address, I can set even 192.999.1.1

How to reproduce the error:

1. Enter an IP address, e.g. 192.168.1.1
2. Select some part, like 192.**__168__**.1.1
3. Start entering numbers, and you get 192.**999**.1.1

How to improve the code to beat this issue?

here is the code I use

```js
// Credits to @t_m27    
var options = {
  onKeyPress: function(text, event, currentField, options) {
    if (text) {
      var ipArray = text.split(".");
      var lastValue = ipArray[ipArray.length - 1];
      if (lastValue != "" && parseInt(lastValue) > 255) {
        ipArray[ipArray.length - 1] = '255';
        var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
        currentField.text(resultingValue).val(resultingValue);
      }
    }
  },
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /[0-9]/,
      optional: true
    }
  }
};

$(".ipaddr").mask("0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ", options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ipaddr" />
```

Comment: Use an *onchange* event to restrict the values. E.g. if it goes out of range, have your event change the value to base min or max that's in range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```js
// Credits to @t_m27    
var options = {
  onKeyPress: function(text, event, currentField, options) {
    if (text) {
      var ipArray = text.split(".");
      ipArray = ipArray.map(num => num > 255 ? 255 : num)
      var resultingValue = ipArray.join(".");
      currentField.text(resultingValue).val(resultingValue);
    }
  },
  translation: {
    'Z': {
      pattern: /[0-9]/,
      optional: true
    }
  }
};

$(".ipaddr").mask("0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ", options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.16/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class="ipaddr" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! Now when I select 168 from 192.168.1.1 and try to set 99 it gives 192.9.91.1. Any way to fix it?

Comment: `ipArray = ipArray.map(num => num > 255 ? 255 : num);`
Shows syntax error. IE 11

Comment: Ie11 does not support the fat arrow - change to function or upgrade to edge chromium

Comment: Very strange. When I run this code in Mozilla here, as a code snipped I have a behaviour I wrote in the first comment. When I run it in my project, it works like a charm, but not in the IE 11. I've changed it to `ipArray = ipArray.map(function (num) { return num > 255 ? 255 : num });` and now IE just freezes

Comment: Okay, now I know why IE freezes, it fires onKeyPress event always when currentField.text is being updated

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use a function that returns true if it is a valid ip, or false otherwise, you can use it like this:

```
function isValidIp(ip) {
  return !ip.split('.').find(part => part > 255);
}
```

You can use this to show a message or perhaps mark the input as invalid.