# how to set input ip-mask with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, input-mask

mask after adding with Ajax
but works without ajax  pleas help me

sample code :

```
 <script src="/static/inputmaskjs/mask.ip-input.js"></script>
 <script src="/static/inputmaskjs/app.js"></script>
            
 <div class="ipv4"></div>
 <script>
 setTimeout(function(){ 
  $('.ipv4').html('<input ip-mask >')
   }, 3000);  // dosent work 
 </script>
                
                 
  <div class="ipv4"><input ip-mask ></div> //not peroplem
            
                enter code here**dose not work ip-mask **
```

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery or Javascript Input IP address mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373425/jquery-or-javascript-input-ip-address-mask)

```
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.10/jquery.mask.js"> 
   </script>
 



  <input class="ipv4">

   $(documnet).on('click','.ipv4',function(){
    
       $('.ipv4').mask('0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ.0ZZ', { translation: { 'Z': { pattern: /[0-9]/, 
       optional: true } } });
            
            })
```