# Ban usage of more than one dots stands to each other

Tags: javascript, ip

I have a question regarding JS function.
So I need to write a program that will return true if ip is correct and false if it is not. I did but there is a part that doesn’t work exactly that I want. So how can I ban usage of ... ? It this case the output will be false. Please see my code and thanks in advance.

```
function IPv4validation(ip) {
    parts = ip.split('.');
    if (parts.length === 4 && parts.map(Number).every(num => num >= 0 && num <= 255)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [IP address validation with proper dots in between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987015/ip-address-validation-with-proper-dots-in-between)